# dispatch_async on DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL after app close

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, appdelegate, dispatch-async

I added some code to my app's applicationWillTerminate method:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create(@"some name", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL), ^{
       //Some Code
    });
```

Is there a chance my code will NOT execute?
I'm having some issues indicating that in some cases this code will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

This method will not be called if your application crash or is suspended.

For more informations, you can see the documentation [Apple documentation (UIApplicationDelegate)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate:) and [Apple documentation (The App Life Cycle)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)

Answer (score -1):

There is a huge chance that it will not execute, or that it starts executing and will be killed in the middle of execution.